# What is the path to the `dir` program on Windows from `cmd.exe`?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, path

This question is interesting because normally I would use `where.exe` on Windows to find the path to a program on my path. However, `where` has an option `dir`, `/r` to recursively search a path. I don't know if there is a pattern or option for `where` to properly interpolate for `dir` or what? It returns `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`. I wonder if `dir` is built into a dll or something somewhere? Anyways, I have no idea where `dir` is. I have a different `dir.exe` program from MinGW `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\dir.exe`. That is not the native Windows `dir` program though.

Several PowerShell one-liners only return emptiness.

```
PS> (Get-Command dir).Source

PS> Get-Command -Name dir

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           dir -> Get-ChildItem
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270559/where-is-programs-path-for-powershell-command

I also wonder if the location is hidden for security purposes or if `dir` is merely so ancient and insignificant it's just in memory or something?

Comment: In MS-DOS it was an internal command in COMMAND.COM and I always assumed it was the same with CMD.EXE in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What is the path to the `dir` program?

It doesn't have one.

`dir` is one of several commands that are internal to the `cmd` shell.

The full list can be found at [Internal commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) and includes:

> `ASSOC`, `BREAK`, `CALL` ,`CD/CHDIR`, `CLS`, `COLOR`, `COPY`, `DATE`,
> `DEL`, `DIR`, `DPATH`, `ECHO`, `ENDLOCAL`, `ERASE`, `EXIT`, `FOR`,
> `FTYPE`, `GOTO`, `IF`, `KEYS`, `MD/MKDIR,` `MKLINK` (vista and above),
> `MOVE`, `PATH`, `PAUSE`, `POPD`, `PROMPT`, `PUSHD`, `REM`,
> `REN/RENAME`, `RD/RMDIR`, `SET`, `SETLOCAL`, `SHIFT`, `START`, `TIME`,
> `TITLE`, `TYPE`, `VER`, `VERIFY`, `VOL`

...

> It is possible for a system to have an internal command and an external command with the same name. If you have a command called `DATE.exe` and want to run that in preference to the internal `DATE` command, use the full pathname to the file e.g. `C:\utils\date.exe` even if your current directory is `C:\utils\`.

So in your case you can run the MingW version of `dir` by using the full path `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\dir.exe` or by running a MingW terminal instead of `cmd` (then `dir` will run the MingW version).

Note that, as you have noticed, `PowerShell` has defined a `dir` alias so that users can run a "dir" command in PowerShell.

> I also wonder if the location is hidden for security purposes or if `dir` is merely so ancient and insignificant it's just in memory or something?

It is essentially in memory, but only when a `cmd` shell is loaded and then can be accessed by typing `dir`. The same applies to all of the other internal commands.

Comment: Thank you, the reference provided is very concise.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `dir` (among many others) is built-into `cmd.exe`.

> The command is usually implemented as an internal command in the
> command-line interpreter (shell).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dir_(command)

- [Here is a list](https://ss64.com/nt/) of built-in commands. Notice the legend/key at
  the bottom of the page. https://ss64.com/nt/

> COMMAND.COM is the default command-line interpreter for MS-DOS,
> Windows 95, Windows 98 and Windows Me. In the case of DOS, it is the
> default user interface as well. It has an additional role as the usual
> first program run after boot (init process), hence being responsible
> for setting up the system by running the AUTOEXEC.BAT configuration
> file, and being the ancestor of all processes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMMAND.COM

> Command Prompt, also known as cmd.exe or cmd, is the default
> command-line interpreter for the OS/2,[1] eComStation, ArcaOS,
> Microsoft Windows (Windows NT family and Windows CE family), and
> ReactOS[2] operating systems.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe